# Entity Framework: How to insert data from a list which does not already exists in DB table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting Data from a `ListBox` and inserting into DB.
Before Data Insert, I need to ensure that the data in the `ListBox` does not already exists in the database. In a nutshell, only insert rows that does not match rows in the database. *Example table below.*

*Data Insert Code:*

```
    private void InsertList()
    {
        var listA = new List<string>();
        var listB = new List<string>();

        //Populate both list by splitting items in listbox

        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            var components = item.Value.Split('/');

            listA.Add(components.First());

            listB.Add(components.Last());
        }

        using (DataContext dataContext = new DataContext())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
            {
                LIST_OBJECTS listObject = new LIST_OBJECTS
                {

        // Need to check data does not already exists in DB before adding.

                    LIST_KEY = 1,
                    LIST_ITEM_A = listA[i],
                    LIST_ITEM_B = listB[i]
                };

                dataContext.LIST_OBJECTS.Add(listObject);
            }

            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

*Example Table:*

In the table below the highlighted data will not be inserted if it exists in the list because it is already in the DB.

[image]

Thanks my friend:

Comment: Which property is the primary key or unique identifier for stuff that already exists in the DB?

Comment: `LIST_ITEM_A` and `LIST_ITEM_B` are both Primary (Composite Key).

Comment: I would do it by adding an if statement: if (dataContext.LIST_OBJECTS.Where (l => l.LIST_ITEM_A == listA [i] && L.LIST_ITEM_B == listB [i]).First() == null) { \\insert}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given it's a somewhat lengthy condition (it wouldn't fit on one line) :

```
        for (var i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!exists(dataContext, listA[i], listB[i])) 
            {
                LIST_OBJECTS listObject = new LIST_OBJECTS
                {
                    LIST_KEY = 1,
                    LIST_ITEM_A = listA[i],
                    LIST_ITEM_B = listB[i]
                };
                dataContext.LIST_OBJECTS.Add(listObject);
            }
        }

        dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

and then a seperate private method:

```
private bool exists(DataContext ctx, string a, string b) 
{
    return ctx.LIST_OBJECTS.Any(i => i.LIST_ITEM_A == a
                             && i => i.LIST_ITEM_B == b);
}
```

Comment: Do you know why I am unable to reference the `listObject` if I attempt to add a statement within the declaration? The object becomes out of scope.

Comment: Because I goofed and I'm not in-front of a compiler right now ;) One second

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion @Peyman, if was a good one, it just got lost in the edit conflict resolution bit

Comment: Sorry for the drag: I am relatively new to Entity Framework. I am still getting errors on the exits Method. E.g: `ctx does not contain a definition for Any.` I am also confused as to how the string parameter  `a` and `b` is able to expose the `LIST_ITEMS_A and B'. Thanks again!

Comment: That's perfectly fine, it was another error on my part. I believe it's been corrected now.